# Debian Buster, XFCE − Firefox keeps forgetting it's been my default browser forever

Tags: firefox, debian, browser, mime-types, xfce4

In the preferences of Firefox itself, the `default browser` box is checked, of course.

In `Settings / Personal / Preferred Applications`, the web browser is set to "Mozilla Firefox" like it should and like it has always been. One thing is odd though : instead of a nice icon there is this generic, nondecript red {×}.

I tried to specify "Other" as `/usr/bin/firefox` but that doesn't change a thing : each time it starts up, it keeps pestering me :

> "Use Firefox as my default browser"

If this is of any relevance : I do occasionally use other browsers, and also several profiles for Firefox proper.

This annoyance is rather new, a couple of days at most, and I can't link it to any significant change in settings or configuration.

---

Addendum : the plot thickens. Looking up, I found [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8252/how-to-launch-default-web-browser-from-the-terminal), which I tested, giving the following :

| command | browser |
| --- | --- |
| `sensible-browser` | Brave |
| `xdg-open` | Firefox |
| `x-www-browser` | Brave |
| `gnome-open` | *(command not found)* |

---

Closure : much solace was found at, of all places, the [Brave Help Center](https://support.brave.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020406572-How-do-I-set-Brave-to-be-my-Default-Browser-), but I still resent *Brave* for behaving like it owns the place. Oddly enough, I also found that *Thunderbird* also thinks it's the only browser in town.

*in fine*

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
sudo update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser
xdg-settings set default-web-browser brave-browser.desktop
```

Comment: Please check the "other browsers". One or more is probably set to default.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - Good idea. Checked. Negative.